# Set Product attribute via PHP - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm simply trying to set a product attribute on a simple woocommerce product.

This is what I have tried with:

```
wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID, 'tekst på mit skilt', text1, False );
```

The slug for the attribute is text1 , I need to set it to: tekst på mit skilt

What am I doing wrong, as it's not set ?

I'm creating a product by the way using this code:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', 'customcart');


function customcart() {

  if (isset($_POST["addcustomcarts"])) {

    global $woocommerce;

    $my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => $_POST["textInput"],
      'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_author'   => 1,
      'post_type'     =>'product'
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    $product_ID = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    if ( $product_ID ){
      wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID, 'design-selv-skilte', 'product_cat' );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_regular_price', 100 );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_price', 100 );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_stock_status', 'instock' );
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_sku', 'designselvskilt' );    
      add_post_meta($product_ID, '_visibility', 'hidden' );
      //wp_set_object_terms( $product_ID, 'tekst på mit skilt', text1, False );

      $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart( $product_ID, $quantity=1 );

      exit( wp_redirect( '/kurv' )  );

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Are you referring to a meta value?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? as in are you trying to change it in the front-end only or inside the DB?

Comment: So what I'm doing is - I create a product, when I do this I also want to set the attribute values of this product. One of those attributes has the name text1 - you follow ?

Comment: I don't understand why you aren't just using `add_post_meta()`...

Comment: @rnevius I have tried that , but how do I use it on product attributes - can you give example with the attribute with name "text1"?

Comment: `add_post_meta($product_ID, 'text1', 'tekst på mit skilt' );`

Comment: Are you referring to a WooCommerce attribute? That's just a custom taxonomy with the letters `pa_` appended to the front. Ex: An attribute with the slug of "color" would really be a taxonomy called "pa_color".

Comment: @helgatheviking  , this works: pa_text1 only issue is that it's not showing under attributes under the product data(backend), only in the bottom within custom fields. How do I make them appear here?

Comment: It should only show up as post meta in the custom fields if you used `add_post_meta()`.